# Word spacing is not working, am I targeting the wrong <>?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

How do I separate the words Colors/Fonts/Images so they are further out apart? Those are links I can click to navigate to different pages using react-router-dom. I just want to separate them with the word spacing a little wider so it looks nice.

current problem

[image]

desired outcome

[image]

react code

```
      <S.LinkContainer>
        <Link to="/projects-main/projects/ui-palettes/colors-palettes">Colors</Link>
        <Link to="/projects-main/projects/ui-palettes/fonts-palettes">Fonts</Link>
        <Link to="/projects-main/projects/ui-palettes/images-palettes">Images</Link>
      </S.LinkContainer>
```

css

```
export const LinkContainer = styled.div`
margin: auto;
flex-direction: column;
word-spacing: 5rem;
`
```

Comment: yes! instead of "justify-content: space-between". i altered it to "justify-content: space-evenly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `flex-direction: column;` nor `word-spacing` are doing what you're expecting

Use `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between`